# Creating a url structure like current-route/edit/{id} in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am very much new to Laravel. During the learning curve I came across a situation which I am going to describe below :

I have a page contains data grid in /manage-clients route. For the grid I am used datatables. I have added edit button for each record. Now, I want to make the edit screen, which is basically a new view. I want the url structure for edit to be /manage-clients/edit/{id}. How to achieve this with the below set-up.?

below is my controller :

```
    public function getIndex()
        {
            return View('admin.manageclients');
        }
        public function anyData()
        {
            $clients    = DB::table('users')
                        ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])
                        ->where('type', '=', '');
            return Datatables::of($clients)->addColumn('action', function ($clients) {
                    return '<a href="edit-client/'.$clients->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>';
                })->editColumn('id', 'ID: {{$id}}')->make(true);
        }
        public function editClient($id)
        {
//This is my edit function which is going to load the details of provided $id into view.
            return $id;
        }
```

My route is :

```
Route::group (array('prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('dashboard',['as'=>'getDashboard', 'uses'=>'Admin\AdminController@getDashBoard']);
    Route::controller('manage-admins', 'Admin\ManageAdminController', ['anyData'  => 'manage-admins.data','getIndex' => 'manage-admins']);
    Route::controller('manage-clients', 'Admin\ManageClientController', ['anyData'  => 'manage-clients.data', 'getIndex' => 'manage-clients']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Route::group (array('prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('dashboard',['as'=>'getDashboard', 'uses'=>'Admin\AdminController@getDashBoard']);
    Route::controller('manage-admins', 'Admin\ManageAdminController', ['anyData'  => 'manage-admins.data','getIndex' => 'manage-admins']);
    Route::controller('manage-clients', 'Admin\ManageClientController', ['anyData'  => 'manage-clients.data', 'getIndex' => 'manage-clients']);
    Route::get('manage-clients/edit/{id}', 'ManageAdminController@editClient');//I have added this code 
});
```

Note that id will be automatically be available to you inside the controller

Comment: Almost. But I am having Controller method not found error.

Note : Corrected the code to below since my controllers are under Controllers/Admin directory.

Route::get('manage-clients/edit/{id}', 'Admin\ManageClientController@editClient');